# how to cancel the after method for an off delay timer in tkinter using python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, methods, logic

I have a off delay program in which when I select the input checkbutton, the output is 1. When I deselect the input checkbutton, the output goes back to 0 after a timer (set up in a scale). For that I use the after method. That part works. My problem is that I want to reset the timer if the checkbutton is selected again before the output went to 0; but once the checkbutton is selected the first time, the after method get triggered and it doesn't stop. I'm trying to use after_cancel, but I can't get it to work. Any solution?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

t1= IntVar()
out = Label(root, text="0")
remain_time = IntVar()
grab_time = 1000

def start_timer(set_time):
    global grab_time
    grab_time = int(set_time) * 1000

def play():
    if t1.get() == 1:
        button1.configure(bg='red')
        out.configure(bg="red", text="1")
    else:
        button1.configure(bg='green')
        def result():
            out.configure(bg="green", text="0")
        out.after(grab_time,result)

button1 = Checkbutton(root,variable=t1, textvariable=t1, command=play)
time = Scale(root, from_=1, to=10, command=start_timer)

button1.pack()
time.pack()
out.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected: when press the checkbutton before the output went to 0, reset the counter.

So you could use the `.after_cencel` when the value of checkbutton is `1`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

t1= IntVar()
out = Label(root, text="0")
remain_time = IntVar()
grab_time = 1000

def start_timer(set_time):
    global grab_time
    grab_time = int(set_time) * 1000

def play():
    if t1.get() == 1:
        button1.configure(bg='red')
        out.configure(bg="red", text="1")
        try: # when the first time you start the counter, root.counter didn't exist, use a try..except to catch it.
            root.after_cancel(root.counter)
        except :
            pass
    else:
        button1.configure(bg='green')
        def result():
            out.configure(bg="green", text="0")
        root.counter = out.after(grab_time,result)

button1 = Checkbutton(root,variable=t1, textvariable=t1, command=play)
time = Scale(root, from_=1, to=10, command=start_timer)

button1.pack()
time.pack()
out.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it works fine, but I after running it I got the following errors                                           Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ochag00f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ochag00f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2302, in destroy
    for c in list(self.children.values()): c.destroy()

Comment: File "C:\Users\ochag00f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2578, in destroy
    Misc.destroy(self)
  File "C:\Users\ochag00f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 630, in destroy
    self.tk.deletecommand(name)
_tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command                                                                              The program worked, just wondering why the errors afterwards....

Comment: @fernando Sorry I couldn't reproduce that.Could you explain how to get that exception?

Comment: It happens to me when I run the code posted here (and exactly the same in a bigger code in my project). If I set the time to... 3 for instance. I select the checkbutton, then I deselect it after 1 second and selected again 1 second later (before out goes to 0) and finally deselect it and wait for out turns to 0. Everything works, but after closing the window I have the error. In my bigger project, i even have another window open with a checkbutton in the middle of the window. I'm using Python 3.8.5

Comment: @fernando But I couldn't reproduce that in this code....